# Date Format Into BiWeekly Buckets In a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data structure

| StartTime | EndTime | BunchOfOtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |

I need to create a new column using a `SELECT` which adds a formatted date falling into *BiWeekly buckets* (Monday - Sunday).

For example, for each row in the result, if `EndTime` has a date between Oct 02 - Oct 15, the new column would show `10/15/23`. If `EndTime` has a date between Oct 16 - Oct 29, the new column would show `10/29/23`,  and so on.

We can assume I will only be working with data occurring on or after Oct 01, 2018, so that can be ground zero for the beginning of the BiWeekly cycle. First Biweekly bucket would be Oct 01, 2018 - Oct 14, 2018, which would be labeled `10/14/2018`.

This needs to be completely contained within a `SELECT` statement, if possible, and not using a `GROUP BY`. I am just adding an additional calculated column to an existing table as a result set

I am currently using the following `SELECT` which formats the `EndTime` into a *weekly* bucket of Monday through Sunday.

```sql
SELECT
    BunchOfOtherColumns
    ,FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EndTime), EndTime), 'MM/dd/yy')
FROM ...
```

This gives me a nice output of

| BunchOfOtherColumns | DateBucket |
| --- | --- |

But now I need BiWeekly buckets

Here is a batch of sample data:

| StartTime | EndTime | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 10:00:00 | 2023-10-01 23:59:00 | Nope |
| 2023-10-02 09:00:00 | 2023-10-02 12:59:00 | Nada |
| 2023-10-12 15:00:00 | 2023-10-12 17:59:00 | Nyet |
| 2023-10-27 10:00:00 | 2023-10-27 23:59:00 | None |

Expected output

| OtherColumns | BiWeeklyBucket |
| --- | --- |
| Nope | 10/01/2023 |
| Nada | 10/15/2023 |
| Nyet | 10/15/2023 |
| None | 10/29/2023 |

Comment: I think you can just use `DATEDIFF` to calculate this.

Comment: How do you define a "BiWeekly" bucket? Also, please provide some sample data and expected results. It's great that you included a text description of your problem, but being able to see concrete _tabular_ data you have as inputs, and what you expect the output to be in each circumstance is how you're really going to get your question answered.

Comment: @Kevin P. Man, believe me I have been trying ridiculous amounts of DATEDIFF with DATEADDs, using Days and Weeks, even trying to calibrate using a 19000101 start date. I cannot get it to properly bucket them into 2 week sections.

Comment: @Xedni The description of Biweekly is in the paragraph. Oct 02 - Oct 15 Mon-Sun = Oct 15, etc. I will add some tabular data in my Q though

Comment: Given any arbitrary date, how do you know if it is in the first week of a new two week period or the second week of the preceding one? You've given a specific example of oct 2 being a grounding date of a new week starting. Let's take the arbitrary date 2022-07-11 (a Monday). Is that part of the two week period beginning with 2022-07-11 and ending with 2022-07-23? Or is it in the middle of the period beginning 2022-07-02 and ending 2022-07-16?

Comment: Forgive me, I think I got the math wrong with my date periods. I guess the correct ranges would be 2022-07-04 to 2022-07-17, or 2022-07-11 to 2022-07-24

Comment: I believe that is one of the speedbumps I am hitting. We can assume that I will only be working with data after Oct 01, 2018. Which can be used as ground zero for setting the BiWeekly cycle. I will add that info to the original question.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If you're already on 2022, there' s a new generate_series() function that might be useful for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(If using SQL Server 2022 or later, see the much simpler answer from Charlieface.)*

Given a reference date that defines a first Monday of any two-week bucket, you can calculate the difference in days and then either calculate `FLOOR(diff / 14.0)` to get a bucket number, or calculate `((diff % 14) + 14) % 14` to calculate the day number relative to the  starting Monday of the containing two-week bucket.

The use of `FLOOR(diff / 14.0)` instead of just `diff / 14` is needed to handle negative offsets. Similarly, the double modulo in `((diff % 14 + 14) % 14` is also needed to map negative numbers to the desired 0..13 range.

```
DECLARE @ReferenceDate DATE = '2023-10-02' -- Reference Monday

;WITH CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-09-01 13:45') Dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D.Dt) AS Dt
    FROM CTE_Dates D
    WHERE D.Dt < '2023-10-31'
)
SELECT
    D.Dt,
    DATENAME(weekday, D.Dt) AS WeekDay,
    DATEDIFF(day, @ReferenceDate, D.Dt) AS DayDiff,
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @ReferenceDate, D.Dt) / 14.0) AS BucketNo,
    ((DATEDIFF(day, @ReferenceDate, D.Dt) % 14) + 14) % 14 AS BucketDay,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, - ((DATEDIFF(day, @ReferenceDate, D.Dt) % 14) + 14) % 14, D.Dt)) AS BucketStartDt,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(day, 13 - ((DATEDIFF(day, @ReferenceDate, D.Dt) % 14) + 14) % 14, D.Dt)) AS BucketEndDt
FROM CTE_Dates D
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Partial results:

| Dt | WeekDay | DayDiff | BucketNo | BucketDay | BucketStartDt | BucketEndDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 13:45 | Sunday | -1 | -1 | 13 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-10-01 |
| 2023-10-02 13:45 | Monday | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-03 13:45 | Tuesday | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-04 13:45 | Wednesday | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-05 13:45 | Thursday | 3 | 0 | 3 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-06 13:45 | Friday | 4 | 0 | 4 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-07 13:45 | Saturday | 5 | 0 | 5 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-08 13:45 | Sunday | 6 | 0 | 6 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-09 13:45 | Monday | 7 | 0 | 7 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-10 13:45 | Tuesday | 8 | 0 | 8 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-11 13:45 | Wednesday | 9 | 0 | 9 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-12 13:45 | Thursday | 10 | 0 | 10 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-13 13:45 | Friday | 11 | 0 | 11 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-14 13:45 | Saturday | 12 | 0 | 12 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-15 13:45 | Sunday | 13 | 0 | 13 | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-16 13:45 | Monday | 14 | 1 | 0 | 2023-10-16 | 2023-10-29 |
| 2023-10-17 13:45 | Tuesday | 15 | 1 | 1 | 2023-10-16 | 2023-10-29 |
| 2023-10-18 13:45 | Wednesday | 16 | 1 | 2 | 2023-10-16 | 2023-10-29 |
| 2023-10-19 13:45 | Thursday | 17 | 1 | 3 | 2023-10-16 | 2023-10-29 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lYVcW0OX).

The original post and subsequent comments have not been consistent as to which Mondays constitute the start or middle of the two-week buckets, but `@ReferenceDate` can be changed as needed to accommodate the final decision. (It need not even be a Monday.)

Comment: That one got it. Appreciate your help and the ability to adjust the Ref Date, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

**In SQL Server 2022, you can just use the [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.**

This can bucketize dates into groups, and you can give it the type and size of the bucket, as well as an origin.

It seems, contrary to what you are stating, that in order to get the buckets to fall out the way you say, you would need to move the origin to `20180924`.

```sql
DATE_BUCKET(week, 2, EndTime, CAST('20180924' AS datetime))
```

To get the end of the bucket, just add 13 days

```sql
DATEADD(day, 13, DATE_BUCKET(week, 2, EndTime, CAST('20180924' AS datetime)))
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-AiQ8RYk)

Comment: The best answer is always: "There's a function for that". Great find. Much simpler than the various tricky calculations in every other answer.

Comment: I hope I have 2022, but I do not believe I do. Will check in the morning. My fault for not specifying, thanks for the answer

Comment: Nope, it's saying that is not an available built in. Appreciate it though. It brings up the help to step me through it in SSMS, but then red lines it if I run the query.

Comment: `SELECT @@version;` will tell you your version number. SSMS sometimes gets confused about syntax, especially if you aren't on the latest version of SSMS.

Comment: SQL Server 2019 RTM. Thanks for that command though, there is so much my skillset is missing since I mainly function from an SSMS pov

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some sort of `DATE` or `DATETIME` column:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT i.*, DATEADD(DAY,1-CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,InvoiceDateTimeUTC) % 2 = 0 THEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)
                 ELSE 7+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)
            END,CAST(InvoiceDateTimeUTC AS DATE)) AS BiWeeklyStartDate,
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,InvoiceDateTimeUTC) % 2 = 0 THEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)
                 ELSE 7+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,InvoiceDateTimeUTC)
            END AS DayNumber
  FROM Invoices i
 ORDER BY CAST(InvoiceDateTimeUTC AS DATE);
```

| InvoiceID | InvoiceDateTimeUTC | CustomerID | EmployeeID | StoreID | BiWeeklyStartDate | DayNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58405 | 2021-06-06 19:46:15.9633333 | 241 | 59 | 47 | 2021-05-24 | 14 |
| 59390 | 2021-06-06 19:46:15.9633333 | 979 | 60 | 15 | 2021-05-24 | 14 |
| 15356 | 2021-06-07 19:48:15.9633333 | 807 | 16 | 28 | 2021-06-07 | 1 |
| 70300 | 2021-06-07 19:47:15.9633333 | 21 | 70 | 5 | 2021-06-07 | 1 |
| 24578 | 2021-06-07 19:48:15.9633333 | 784 | 25 | 57 | 2021-06-07 | 1 |

You can adjust the start day using `SET DATEFIRST` and adjust the weeks by changing the modulo.

Comment: There seem to be some continuity issues with using `DATEPART(WEEK, ...)` as dates cross year boundaries, jumping from 53 to 1 on some cases and 54 to 1 in others. For most years, the 53 to 1 transition covers 7 days, which is okay. For some years like 2005/2006 and 2011/2012, the 53 to 1 transition covers 14 days. 2000/2001 and 2028/2029 transition from 54 to 1 and spans 7 days, but is an even/odd mix. See [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ngl7Dw_c). A possible fix that could still allow for week-based-arithmetic may be to replace `DATEPART()` with `DATEDIFF(week, 0, date)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple arithmetic to calculate this.

Consider

`(DATEADD(DAY, (FLOOR((1 - (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-9-30', EndTime) / 14.0 % 1)) * 14)) + 7, EndTime))`

```
SELECT  BunchOfOtherColumns
       ,FORMAT((DATEADD(DAY,(FLOOR((1 - (DATEDIFF(DAY,'2018-9-30',EndTime) / 14.0 % 1)) * 14)) + 7,EndTime)) ,'MM/dd/yy')
FROM ...
```

I don't quite see how 10/15/23 would be an end so perhaps I am off. I would think it would be the 8th or 22nd but for this reason I add a +7.

Comment: Kevin - I think you need to double check the above answer. It fails even with the initial condition - mapping a 2018-09-30 date to 2018-10-21 - well outside the containing two-week bucket.